# Autosize Font & Wrap text in a Listview

Tags: wpf, listview, autosize, wrappanel

I have a listview that can contain anywhere between 1 & 10 items of text. The ListView must be contained in a specific size of a grid.

I want each item be able to wrap onto another row (Which I can get working ok) but when the items eventually reach the bottom of the Grid region, I then want the items to resize in font, maintaining the wrapped text & not allowing an scrolling.

I may be asking too much of WPF or not explaining this very well.

```
    <ListView Name="lvWrap" ItemsSource="{Binding Directions}" Style="{DynamicResource ListViewStyle1}" FontSize="29">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel Name="MainGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

This wraps every item ok, but the bottom items dissapear off screen. I dont want this to happen

Answer (score 0):

You're not asking too much... just about anything is possible with WPF. However, you *are* asking a lot and most likely, too much for users here. The only way that I could imagine that you could achieve your requirement is for you to implement a custom `Panel` and set it as the `ListView.ItemsPanel`.

Inside a `Panel`, or more specifically, the `ArrangeOverride` method of the `Panel` is one of the few places where you could detect that the items have reached the bottom of the available space. While creating a custom `Panel` is not too difficult, it is also no menial task. If you choose to do this, you can take a look at one of the following links in order to get a better understanding of how this is done:

[How to create a Custom Layout Panel in WPF](http://wpftutorial.net/CustomLayoutPanel.html)

[Creating Custom Panels In WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37348/Creating-Custom-Panels-In-WPF)